# Erro na execução da função fromJson

Tags: json, flutter

quando chamo o item dentro do json me retorna esse erro informando que o campo não pode ser nulo, mas na apresentação da classe não tem nenhum atributo nulo.

```
class Movie {
```

String title;
String contentRating;
String distributor;
String urlKey;
String siteURL;
String nationalSiteURL;
String siteURLByTheater;
String nationalSiteURLByTheater;
String boxOfficeId;
String ancineId;
List images;

Movie(
{this.title,
this.contentRating,
this.distributor,
this.urlKey,
this.siteURL,
this.nationalSiteURL,
this.siteURLByTheater,
this.nationalSiteURLByTheater,
this.boxOfficeId,
this.ancineId,
this.images});

Movie.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
title = json['title'];
contentRating = json['contentRating'];
distributor = json['distributor'];
urlKey = json['urlKey'];
siteURL = json['siteURL'];
nationalSiteURL = json['nationalSiteURL'];
siteURLByTheater = json['siteURLByTheater'];
nationalSiteURLByTheater = json['nationalSiteURLByTheater'];
boxOfficeId = json['boxOfficeId'];
ancineId = json['ancineId'];
if (json['images'] != null) {
images = [];
json['images'].forEach((v) {
images.add(Images.fromJson(v));
});
}
}

[quem puder ajudar eu passo o link do repositório.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpqCS.png)

Answer (score 0):

No Flutter, existe um conceito chamado de Null-Safety, basicamente o que ele significa é que uma variável **pode**, em algum momento, ser nula (null). Isso é muito funcional quando trabalhamos com API's, visto que o retorno de uma API pode, em muitos casos, ser nulo. Para resolver esse problema, basta adicionar um ponto de interrogação "?" logo depois do **tipo** do sua variável, por exemplo:

```
class Movie {
     String? title;
     String? contentRating;
     String? distributor;
     String? urlKey;
     String? siteURL;
     String? nationalSiteURL;
     String? siteURLByTheater;
     String? nationalSiteURLByTheater;
     String? boxOfficeId;
     String? ancineId;
     List? images;

     Movie({this.title, 
            this.contentRating, 
            this.distributor, 
            this.urlKey, 
            this.siteURL, 
            this.nationalSiteURL, 
            this.siteURLByTheater, 
            this.nationalSiteURLByTheater, 
            this.boxOfficeId, 
            this.ancineId, 
            this.images});

     Movie.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) { 
         title = json['title']; 
         contentRating = json['contentRating']; 
         distributor = json['distributor']; 
         urlKey = json['urlKey']; 
         siteURL = json['siteURL']; 
         nationalSiteURL = json['nationalSiteURL']; 
         siteURLByTheater = json['siteURLByTheater']; 
         nationalSiteURLByTheater = json['nationalSiteURLByTheater']; 
         boxOfficeId = json['boxOfficeId']; 
         ancineId = json['ancineId']; 
         if (json['images'] != null) { 
             images = []; 
             json['images'].forEach((v) { 
                 images.add(Images.fromJson(v)); 
             }); 
         }
}
```